# Анализ слова "глубокопочитаемый"

Tags: словообразование

Употребимых сочетаний видел не мало, "глубокопочитаемый... ФИО и пр.", даже раздельно. "почёт! в корне приобретает двусмысленность, монолитность - неблагозвучность, поразмышляем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Глубокоуважаемый уже есть, зачем еще глубокопочитаемый? Это слово официального стиля, а "почитать" уж никак к официальному не относится. Вот и всё, очень просто.